# Is there a PowerShell equivalent to the dir /w of the old Windows command prompt?

Tags: powershell, directory, formatted

In the older Windows command prompt `dir /w` formatted the directory output in wide format, providing a more at-a-glance view of contents to pick out folder names without having to scroll through the larger output that happens when they are all stacked vertically. This is especially useful when in VS Codes integrated terminal where the terminal window size is often restricted. Does PowerShell have an equivilent?

Comment: dir | format-wide

Comment: https://blog.stevex.net/powershell-cheatsheet/

Comment: If you really want the exact same output of dir /w just use this command in powershell

`cmd /r dir /w`

Comment: Good point, @DSSO21, but you have a typo: `/r` -> `/c`

Comment: @mklement0 `cmd /r dir /w` works on my System

Comment: @DSSO21. - wow, I've never seen this in the wild, but you're right: `/r` is ia a _compatibility alias_ for `/c`; from `cmd /?`: "Also, for compatibility reasons, /X is the same as /E:ON, /Y is the same as /E:OFF and /R is the same as /C."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This final, and my preferred, solution involves creating a function in my Powershell profile:

```
function List-Wide
{
    Get-ChildItem | Format-Wide -Column 5
}
```

Then, further down in my profile script, setting an alias to call this function:

```
Set-Alias -Name lsw -Value List-Wide
```

Answer (score 1):

`cmd /r dir /w` as suggested by **DSSO21** in the Comments above gives me the result I was expecting, albeit a more verbose command than I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

are you after this?

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -Property Name
```

It should be an equivalent of "dir /w". If I remember correctly.

Comment: This results in a single column.

Comment: Oh mmm I'm not sure you can achieve the same view from powershell  I'll give it a try later on and let you know if I can find a different way to show those info

Comment: Try using this on powershell:
cmd /c dir /w

Comment: That does work, but if someone were trying to stay native PowerShell, it wouldn't be the trick they were looking for.

Comment: I don't think there's another way, because powershell way to display things isn't as cmd. @Br.Bill

Comment: This suggestion is getting there but the command only gives two columns. The answer I give below using cmd /r dir /w is what I was expecting, as the number of columns adjusts to the horizontal size of my terminal window